# Why do one need a Factory Pattern as i could accomplish the task using polymorphism?

Tags: java

I have a classes and interface as shown

```
package com;

public interface Animal {

    public void makeSound();

}
```

**Dog.java**

```
package com;

public class Dog implements Animal {

    @Override
    public void makeSound() {

        System.out.println("Ruf Ruf");

    }

}
```

**Cat.java**

```
package com;

public class Cat implements Animal {

    @Override
    public void makeSound() {

        System.out.println("Meow Meow");

    }

}
```

**Tester.java**

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Tester tester = new Tester();
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        Cat cat = new Cat();

        tester.show(dog);

    }

    public void show(Animal animal) {

        animal.makeSound();
    }

}
```

**Why do one need a Factory Pattern as i could accomplish the task using polymorphism?**

I was following this tutorial tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm so in this case what is the use of ShapeFactory class here ??

Comment: Accomplish *what*?. A *factory* creates objects of a particular type. What you are doing here is just dynamically dispatching methods based on the type of object (which you are creating yourself).

Comment: I have problems to understand your question. What do you want to achieve? And why/how to you want to use a factory pattern?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion , i was following this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm so in this case what is the use of ShapeFactory  class here ??

Comment: @PreethiJain - That tutorial is correct. Check steps 3 and 4.

Comment: Simply imagine that the step 4 of your tutorial consists in asking the end user "please enter a shape". The factory is then useful to get a Shape instance from the entered shape name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factory Pattern is used to create Objects i/e, it is a *Creational Pattern*. 
In your example if you had a class `AnimalFactory`, which produced your cats and dogs, then it would be a factory pattern.

What you are really doing in *your posted* code is creating the `Dog` and `Cat` objects yourself and calling an overridden method (which is dynamically dispatched based on the object type). In factory pattern you depend on another *entity* to generate your objects for you

Comment: Just as an additional point: The intention of the factory pattern is to decouple the object construction. In your example the creation is trivial, but imagine an object whichs construction is more complex and requires e.g. the initialization of many fields. Furthermore it allows to you replace implementations without touching the client code (e.g. replace the normal implementation with a mock).

Answer (score 1):

IF you take a look at [implementing-factory-design-pattern-in-java](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/23/implementing-factory-design-pattern-in-java/) you'll see a factory based on an enumeration.

so here one could use an Animal factory, have an

```
enum AnimalFamily { CAT, DOG }
```

and use that to create animals.

I doubt the factory pattern makes sense here.

However discovery of capabilities (lookup) is similar to the factory pattern.
And concerns this case.

Usage:

```
Optional<MakingSound> soundCapability = animal.lookup(MakingSound.class);
if (soundCapability.isPresent()) {
    makingSound.makeSound();
}

interface Animal {
    <T> Optional<T> lookup(Class<T> klazz);
}

interface MakingSound {
    void makeSound();
}

// Base class
class AbstractAnimal implements Animal {
    protected Map<Class<?>, Object> capabilities;

    @Override
    public <T> Optional<T> lookup(Class<T> klazz) {
        Object capability = capabilities.get(klazz);
        T c = klazz.cast(capability);
        return Optional.ofNullabel(c);
    }
}

class Dog extends Abstract Animal {
    Dog() {
        capabilities.put(MakingSound.class, new MakingSound() {
            @Override
            public void makeSound() {
                System.out.println("Ruf Ruf");
            }
        });

        // Java 8 style
        capabilities.put(MakingSound.class,
            () -> System.out.println("Ruf Ruf"));
    }
}
```

This allows fish without making sounds, adding dynamic capabilties like flying. And so on.
Whether this is done as factory or as above, using a prefilled map, ...

(I have use java 8's Optional here as it fits.)